# How to register an AutoMapper profile with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-container, automapper

I have the following AutoMapper profile:

```
public class AutoMapperBootstrap : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Data.EntityFramework.RssFeed, IRssFeed>().ForMember(x => x.NewsArticles, opt => opt.MapFrom(y => y.RssFeedContent));
        CreateMap<IRssFeedContent, Data.EntityFramework.RssFeedContent>().ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());
    }
}
```

And I am initializing it like this:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
       cfg.AddProfile(new AutoMapperBootstrap());
});

container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>("Mapper", config.CreateMapper());
```

When I try to inject it in my constructor:

```
private IMapper _mapper;
public RssLocalRepository(IMapper mapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

I recieve the following error:

> The current type, AutoMapper.IMapper, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

How can I initialize the AutoMapper profile properly with Unity, so that I can use the mapper anywhere through DI?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your example you are creating named mapping:

```
// named mapping with "Mapper name"
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>("Mapper", config.CreateMapper());
```

But how your resolver will know about this name?

You need to register you mapping without name:

```
// named mapping with "Mapper name"
container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper());
```

It will map your mapper instance to `IMapper` interface and this instance will be returned on resolving interface

Answer (score 1):

You can register it like so:

```
container.RegisterType<IMappingEngine>(new InjectionFactory(_ => Mapper.Engine));
```

Then you can inject it as `IMappingEngine`.

```
private IMappingEngine_mapper;
public RssLocalRepository(IMappingEnginemapper)
{
    _mapper = mapper;
}
```

More information found here:

https://kalcik.net/2014/08/13/automatic-registration-of-automapper-profiles-with-the-unity-dependency-injection-container/