# Registering AutoMapper with Unity fails

Tags: automapper, unity-container

I have the following code to register Mapping (version 4.2)

```
public class ModelMapperProfile : Profile
{

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Case, CaseModel>();
        CreateMap<CaseDetail, CaseDetailModel>();
    }
}
public static class AutoMapperService
{
    public static MapperConfiguration Initialize()
    {
        MapperConfiguration config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<ModelMapperProfile>();
        });

        return config;
    }
}
```

And I register the dependency using unity as follows...

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{

    container.LoadConfiguration();
    var mapper = AutoMapperService.Initialize()
                                .CreateMapper();
    container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(mapper);
}
```

My here service constructor..

```
public TaxLiabilityCaseService(IMapper mapper,
        IUnitOfWork unitofWork,
        IRepository<Case> caseR,
        IRepository<CaseDetail> caseDetailR)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _unitofWork = unitofWork;
        _caseR = caseR;
        _caseDetailR = caseDetailR;
    }
```

And I get the following error message..

> The current type, AutoMapper.IMapper, is an interface and cannot be
>   constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

[Answers found here did not work for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36780573/how-to-register-an-automapper-profile-with-unity/41508695#41508695)

What am I missing here

Answer (score 3):

Try following these steps (MVC5):

Get Unity Nuget package:

```
Unity.Mvc5
```

Create this class:

```
public class MapperConfig
    {
        public static IMapper Mapper { get; set; }
        public static void RegisterProfiles()
        {
            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
               // add profiles here
            });
            config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            Mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }
    }
```

In the `UnityConfig` file (created by the package), add this:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
     {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          container.RegisterInstance<IMapper>(MapperConfig.Mapper);
     }
```

In the `Global.asax`, add these:

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            MapperConfig.RegisterProfiles();
            UnityConfig.RegisterComponents(); 
        }
```

You should be good after this.

Comment: First one: It is not working as you need the actual object to register and null is not allowed.

Comment: @user2984500...What kind of project are you working in?  What is "mapper"?  You're on the right track, but need to structure it properly.

Comment: It is MVC 5 and trying to wire up AutoMapper to map between Entity to Model. 

I use "WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod" to bootstrap the dependencies(unity).

Comment: if you are using static Mapper , why do you need to inject? you can just call as MapperConfig.Mapper.Map, cant you?